# The CAR algebra is simple and nuclear

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

It is a fact that $CAR$ algebra is simple and nuclear.How to show this conclusion?

Comment: In Davidson's book "$C^\ast$-algebras by example"there is a chapter on AF-algebras. If i recall correctly there was a descriptions of their ideals in terms of Bratelli diagrams there. It could be interesting for you to have a look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $I$ be an ideal in the CAR-algebra. Then you should convince yourself that 
$$
 I = \overline{\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty I \cap M_{2^n}}.
$$
Now $I \cap M_{2^n}$ is an ideal in $M_{2^n}$ and you use that $M_{2^n}$ is simple.

For nuclearity, note that there are conditional expectations $M_{2^\infty} \to M_{2^n}$.

Comment: In short, the CAR algebra is simple and nuclear because it is a UHF algebra.

Comment: This is not an argument. What I wrote shows that every UHF algebra is simple and nuclear.

Comment: Of course you have to prove this, as you did. I was just pointing out that one crucial step is to see the CAR algebra as inductive limit of simple and nuclear algebras. Depending on your definition, this might not be obvious.

Comment: Okay, I see your point.